# What is the use of Backbonejs router?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am using backbonejs in my application and loved it. To go to different views, i used Router.
Like i had a button, and clicking it would trigger `#newUrl`. It would go to router and then i could start showing and hiding the views.

I have now started learning bootstrap for the css. I am using `nav-tabs` now to hide and show the views. So i just wanted to ask what is the use of Backbone.Router ?

In what scenarios it would be used ?

Should I stick with old-method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routers are used for routing addresses.  If you're in a single page application that has a users view and a pictures view, you would seemingly want the user to be able to go to `mysite.com/users` and `mysite.com/pics` to access the users and pics.  Without a router, your single page application can only take them to the main page, and then they have to manually navigate your site each time to get back to that view.

With a router, though, if a user wants to bookmark a picture page, they can.  And when they visit that bookmarked address, the router will filter it and see that you've setup the pics view to render whenever someone visits `mysite.com/pics`.

Comment: @AshishNegi that's mostly what they're used for, URL routing.  If you want a quick tutorial visit this page: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/